# Virtual Reality unity SDK

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

Is there a way that I can limit the rotation of my vr camera x axis to only 160 degree instead of 360 . I'm making a racing car game that need to stop the rotation if it reaches a 160 degree. For now I made the color black at the back so that i he/she reaches greater than 160 degree the vision will be just black but I don't want that. Could some please tell me if it is possible?

Comment: did you try checking in an Update that asks for the rotation and rotates the camera if it's out of bounds? Idk if that's possible with VR sdk but worth trying

Comment: did that but it breaks my camera .

Comment: Please add the code of what you tried already

Comment: It is very difficult to limit the physical camera in its rotation! You could limit how much it can turn from the Startpoint **but** this might result in cybersickness because the user might turn his head more but not getting a visual feedback ...